# .htaccess and web.config on same directory?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config

> Can i have .htaccess and web.config on same directory ???
>
> I have IIS shared server.
>   I have blog detail page,that i want to hide.

Actual
https://www.domain.com/detail.php?s=a-felis-incorporated

Required
https://www.domain.com/blog/a-felis-incorporated

I attached .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf)$ /$1.$2 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^pn/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ blog.php?pn=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: IT SHOWS ME BLANK PAGE WHEN I TRY TO CALL ::https://www.domain.com/blog/a-felis-incorporated 
THE SAME URL WILL WORK ON LINUX SERVER.